# Does xcopy pause until copying is complete?

Tags: c#-3.0, xcopy, robocopy

For an C# console app like this is it better to use xcopy or robocopy?
Also, Does xcopy pause until copying is complete?

```
// copy web project to temp
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\xcopy.exe";
            //proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Users\Aron\Pictures\sql-help C:\temp\633965882226105579 /E /I";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}  /E /I", TemplateDemoSiteFolder, SitePath);
            proc.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(9000); // pause for 9 seconds -not very safe though
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of Thread.Sleep(); you probably want to use proc.WaitForExit();